# is Firebase Messaging Service vulnerable to malicious Intent?

Tags: android, security, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-security

I found that FCM `<service>` declaration in `AndroidManifest.xml` is exported (by the `<intent-filter>`) but is not protected by any permission:

```
<service android:name=".firebase.MessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But in GCM the service is protected (not exported, possibly started by an in-app broadcast receiver) ([source](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm#update_the_android_manifest_1)).

I tried to send a custom Intent via `adb shell am startservice` to the messaging service, but nothing happened, maybe Google made their only protection against this, or perhaps I didn't do it right?

So I wonder if FCM is guaranteed to be immune of a malicious Intent attack? Is there any offical documentation/clarification on this?

Comment: If nothing happened, and there were no errors in LogCat, then your `Intent` was delivered successfully, and the service just chose to ignore it. That would leave open the possibility that some other `Intent` might contain something that causes the service to crash. If, OTOH, the OS logged messages in LogCat saying that the service could not be started or something, that would indicate that the service is perhaps being defended better.

Comment: @CommonsWare Nothing was logged in my logcat related to Firebase (limited to my own app but as the service resides in my app I think it's sufficient), so I think the service chose to ignore it in this case. But I'm a bit paronoid and suspect if some other data would get the intent into my app and it can be a security flaw in my case. If I were Google I would have signed the message on server and verify it in the receiver, but I didn't find any documentation on this (and the SDK is close-sourced) so I'm a bit worried.

Comment: I haven't worked with FCM (and haven't touched GCM either in a few years). If `com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService` and the separate Play Services app are communicating via bound services, `FirebaseMessagingService` could be checking to see if the calling UID is tied to the Play Services app, and if that app has the proper signing key. But, as you mention, this is all closed-source, and so it would take some reverse-engineering to determine what defenses they have.